# Ruby on rails: expect ActiveRecord::Relation object but get Model itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can't understand why I am getting Model object instead of Relation object.
Model `Activity`, controller  index action:

```
clacc ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @activities = Activity.my(current_user).filter(filtering_params)
end
```

`:my` is valid scope, `filtering_params` is a hash with key's names same as scopes in the model. Method `filter` defined in module:

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveRecord::Concern

  def filter(filtering_params)
    results = self
    filtering_params.each do |key, value|
      results = results.public_send(key, value)
    end
    results
  end
end
```

If `filtering_params` is not empty hash, everything works fine and `@activities` is Relation object. But if it happend by mistake empty hash passed as argument to `filter` method, I am starting get an error in the view "undefined method each for #Class...".
I try it in console and find what in this case `@activities.object_id` is the same as `Activity.object_id`. But please explain how expected relation object becames a model class itself?

`filtering_params` method in controller:

```
private

def filtering params
  params.merge!(completed: "false") unless params[:comleted]
  params.merge!(select_all: "true") unless params[:select_all]
  params.slice(:completed, :select_all)
end
```

Model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
include Filterable
...
scope :my, -> (user) { # scope here }
scope :completed, # other scope
scope :select_all, # other scope
```

Comment: Can you post the exact and entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to figure out but I guess that when you are assigning `results = self`, you are doing it at class level. If you change this to, in example, `results = self.where(nil)`, you'll be pointing to a collection.

Alternatively you can add the clause:

```
results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
```